# Shell script whitespace escaping

Tags: json, bash, escaping, sh, whitespace

**Edit:** This question has been edited for context. 1.sh and 2.sh scripts in the original question are replaced by their real-world implementations: monitor.sh and api-check.sh respectively.

**Function:**

```
function checkAlive() {
    script="$1"
    args="${@:2}"
    startCheck=$(date +%s)
    echo "$@"
    tempResult="$( "$@" )"
    T_RC="$?"
    if [ "$T_RC" -ne 0 ]; then
        if [ "$result" = "" ]; then
            result="ERRORS: $tempResult"
        else
            result="$result ,, $tempResult"
        fi
    fi
    RC="$((RC > T_RC ? RC : T_RC))"
    timePassed
}
```

**api-check.sh:**

```
method="$1"
url="https://$2"
jwt="$3"
body="$4"
echo "$body"

if ! response="$(curl -s --request "$method" "$url" -w "%{http_code}" --header \
    'Authorization: Bearer '"$jwt" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --data-raw "$body")"; then
    echo "$url curl error getting code: $response"
    exit 2
fi
```

**monitor.sh:**

```
api_url="foo"
oauth_token"bar"
body='{"address":"Test address"}'
checkAlive "api-check.sh" '"POST" "'$api_url'" "'$oauth_token'" '"'$body'"''
```

**Execution Flow:**

- monitor.sh passes the string json body as an argument to checkAlive function (defined above).
- Within checkAlive, the **echo "$@"** returns:

```
api-check.sh "POST" "foo" "bar" '{"address":"Test address"}'
```

- The api-check.sh script never executes properly due to some escaping issue again

**Question:**
What json body should I pass as an argument to checkAlive to escape correctly **OR** Which line of code and in which script do I need to modify to evaluate the json body correctly?

Comment: The culprit is `eval $script $args`. First, you don't double-quote your variable expansions (`'{"address":"Test address"}'` becomes `'{"address":"Test'` `'address"}'`), then even if you double-quote them, `eval` will jinx it... the correct way is to simply use `result="$( "$@" )"`

Comment: If you really need to store all but the first argument, use an array, like `args=("${@:2}")`, then use it like `result=$("$script" "${args[@]}")`. Avoid `eval`, it's extremely hard to use correctly, and almost never necessary.

Comment: Why are you using `"${@:2}"` instead of simply `"$2"`?

Comment: Further, what is the point of `checkAlive` instead of just calling `2.sh` on the given JSON?

Comment: `'"'$body'"''?? Jsut `"$body"`

Comment: @Fravadona suggested that eval is not suitable so I replaced this in the edit without success. The context behind the checkAlive function is now available in the edit and the result for "${@:2}" and "$2" are interchangeable. Hopefully this clears up confusion and I look forward to a response!

Comment: @KamilCuk This is necessary since the checkAlive function takes multiple values for the second argument $2 in the form of a string and if the '"' around $body is not used then the json body requires the double-quotes to be escaped

Comment: No. Quoting is not about how you _pass_ the variable, it's how you _use_ it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- do `func()` not `function func()`
- just `"$var"`. not anything else. Just make sure any `$var` is inside `"` `"`. Nothing more required.

Do:

```
api_url="foo"
oauth_token"bar"
body='{"address":"Test address"}'
checkAlive "api-check.sh" "POST" "$api_url" "$oauth_token" "$body"
```